# while not expression and boolean understanding

Tags: python, boolean

I found this in order to generate random numbers.

```
def main():
    randomNumber = randint(1,100)
    found = False
    while not found:
        userGuess = input("")
        if userGuess == randomNumber:
          print "You win."
          found = True
        elif
          .....
        else
          .....
```

So my question is about 'while not found', I don't find this is instinctive.
More instinctive but not working should be something like:

```
found = False
while found
```

--> the loop is working while found is false

Could someone explain this?

Comment: Then you should write `while found == false` which is a literal translation of your text, "while found is false".

Comment: Fix your indentation; `while found` means `while found == True` and `while not found` means `while found == False`

Answer (score 3):

A `while` loop will execute while the given expression is `True`. In your case, the given expression is `not found`. Since `found` starts off as `False`, `not found` is of course `True`, hence the loop executes and will continue to execute until `found` is set to `True`, at which point `not found` will be `False`.

My advice would be to not rewrite this - it is actually very readable as it is. You are saying that **while** you have **not** **found** something, keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

If `while not found` seems unintuitive, you should probably just get used to it. It's a common Python idiom and will seem very intuitive after a while (pun intended).

If you want more readable code, though, I would get rid of the `found` variable entirely and use `break` to terminate the loop:

```
def main():
    randomNumber = randint(1,100)
    while True:
        userGuess = input("")
        if userGuess == randomNumber:
            print "You win."
            break
        # Code here will run only if the break isn't executed.
        # You don't need the elif any more.
```

It is a matter of personal preference: some people like to use a flag variable to terminate a loop; I prefer the simplicity of an explicit break in code like this.